# How to extend knockout observables to read default value from binding?

Tags: knockout.js, asp.net-mvc-4

I have finally found the time to start learning KnockoutJS while building a new MVC4 application. I am trying to figure out the best way to initialize an observable value from a default value that is already set in the view.

This is a contrived example, but I would like to render out a default value for an observable directly to the view as follows:

```
<input type="hidden" 
       value="@Model.SomeValue"
       data-bind="value: myObservableReference"/>
```

I know that a default value is normally initialized via:

```
model.myObservableReference = ko.obervable("SomeValue");
```

However, I would like to find a way to extend the initialization such that:

```
model.myObservableReference = ko.obervable();
```

would read the existing value from the binding if a value exists.

As I have so far managed to keep my KnockoutJS code completely unaware of the razor world, I want to to avoid the sloppiness of:

```
model.myObservableReference = ko.obervable(@Model.SomeValue);
```

I am guessing this would be handled via either an extender or custom binder, but if someone could point me in the right direction it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Calgary, while it is sometimes useful to do this, it may be a better practice most of the time to serialize your model into JSON, and use it to construct your viewmodel so that it starts with the value, instead of trying to read it from the view. MVVM practices are that the view should never contain data.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Initialize Knockout observable from element attribute value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11526216/initialize-knockout-observable-from-element-attribute-value)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Giving initial value to observable from the HTML markup](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12125143/giving-initial-value-to-observable-from-the-html-markup)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You could try creating your own custom binding handler to achieve this:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.initializeValue = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        valueAccessor()(element.getAttribute('value'));
    },
    update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        var value = valueAccessor();
        element.setAttribute('value', ko.utils.unwrapObservable(value))
    }
};

<input type="hidden" value="@Model.SomeValue"
       data-bind="initializeValue:myObservableReference, value: myObservableReference"/>
```

Comment: This code looks familiar =) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11526216/initialize-knockout-observable-from-element-attribute-value/11526775#11526775

Comment: @Tyrsius - Yes, it would seem to be a duplicate question. I am surprised I didn't come across it as I was actually googling for a while before I posted the question.

Comment: Man I didn't even notice it until just now, but KodeKreacher asked that question. I should pay more attention.

Comment: does this only work if "initializeValue" comes before "value"?

Answer (score 1):

For you googlers out there, here is the code to extend the initializeValue binding to a select box as well as input boxes

```
ko.bindingHandlers.initializeValue = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        if (element.getAttribute('value')) {
            valueAccessor()(element.getAttribute('value'));
        } else if (element.tagName === 'SELECT') {
            valueAccessor()(element.options[element.selectedIndex].value);
        }
    },
    update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        var value = valueAccessor();
        element.setAttribute('value', ko.utils.unwrapObservable(value));
    }
}
```

**NOTE: The initializeValue binding should appear before the value binding in your select's data-bind attribute or it will not work.**

```
<select data-bind='initializeValue: layout_id, value: layout_id, options: layouts, optionsText: "text", optionsValue: "id"'></select>
```