# How to set value in Date type field

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, knockout.js

I have the below HTML and JS and I am using MVC.
Here is the scenario

When the *"Filter"* object parameters are passed in to the HTML I am unable to assign the date field from the KO *"optionsAfterRender"* function.

**HTML (Razor View):**

```
 var Filter =(Project.Models.Entity) ViewData["Filter"];

 @if (Filter != null)
                {
                    <div id="sdate">
                        <label>From Senior Date</label>
                        <input id="sdateVal"   type="date"  data-bind="value:SeniorDate,optionsAfterRender:function(){setOptionSrDate(@Filter.DateSenior.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));}">
                    </div>

                    <div id="jdate">
                        <label>To Junior Date</label>
                        <input id="jdateVal"  type="date"  data-bind="value:JuniorDate,optionsAfterRender:function(){setOptionJrDate(@Filter.DateJunior.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));}">
                    </div>
                }
```

JS (Knockout):

```
  self.setOptionSrDate = function (x) {//Sr Date
        $("#sdateVal").val(x);//this does not assign the value
        self.SeniorDate(x);//this does not assign the value
    };
```

Comment: I am guessing does it have to do with the data binding.When using the same for options binding in dropdowns I was able to achieve this but not with text or date since the have 'data-bind:value'

Answer (score 1):

The problem might be the format of the date. Try this.

```
var now = new Date();

var day = ("0" + now.getDate()).slice(-2);
var month = ("0" + (now.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);

var today = now.getFullYear()+"-"+(month)+"-"+(day) ;

$('#datePicker').val(today);
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears as though you want to initialize your observable with a value taken from the HTML element.

Ideally you want to be able to do this:

```
<input type="date" value="(@Filter.DateSenior.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"))" data-bind="value:SeniorDate">
```

However, this will not work, as I'm sure you have tried, because the default behaviour of the `value` binding does not update the bound observable with the *value* on the *dom* element when the binding is initialized.

But there is a solution, you can create a custom binding that does everything the existing `value` binding does and also the behaviour you want, which is to initialize the observable with the *value* of the *dom* element.

Use this binding:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.value2 = {
  init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings) {
    var observable = valueAccessor(),
      value = element.value;
    observable(value);
    ko.bindingHandlers.value.init.apply(this, arguments);
  },
  update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings) {
    ko.bindingHandlers.value.update.apply(this, arguments);
  }
};
```

Which will enable you to do this:

```
<input type="date" value="(@Filter.DateSenior.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"))" data-bind="value2:SeniorDate">
```

See the working snippet below:

```js
ko.bindingHandlers.value2 = {
  init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings) {
    var observable = valueAccessor(),
      value = element.value;
    observable(value);
    ko.bindingHandlers.value.init.apply(this, arguments);
  },
  update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings) {
    ko.bindingHandlers.value.update.apply(this, arguments);
  }
};

var vm = {
  seniorDate: ko.observable()
};

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<div>
  <input type="date" value="2015-07-20" data-bind="value2: seniorDate" />
</div>

<div>
  <p data-bind="text: seniorDate"></p>
</div>
```

[RP Niemeyer](http://www.knockmeout.net/) has answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12135780/1062224).