# How does one restore a form's previous value in Knockout.js?

Tags: knockout.js

I have a page which has pre-populated inputs on it, and I would like to be able to use that initial value as the initial value for Knockout.

Example:

```
 <input 
      name="Address1" 
      type="text" 
      id="Address1" 
      class="input--textbox" 
      value="213 Fourth st." 
      data-bind="value:Address1" />
```

It seems like the most obvious solution is:

```
this.Address1 = ko.observable(document.getElementById("Address1").value)
```

But that feels like it defeats the very purpose of using something like Knockout in the first place.

Is there a way I could either pass a parameter to Knockout, or use some extension which would default the value to the one provided by the form?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/q/11596933/866172

Comment: Normally the initial value is defined in your View Model, not in the value of the input field

Answer (score 0):

You have to remember that knockout.js is a two-way binding framwork. This obviously means that what goes into the dom element, is reflected in the model. Additionally, in the inverse is true, what goes into the model, is reflected in the dom element.

So you just need to make sure to load your data into your model and the UI will reflect all the prepopulated data you are trying to setup.

Here is my typical approach:

```
function MyModel(data) {
    var self = this;
    //declare properties here


    self.load = function(data) {
        if (data) {
            //set properties here
        }
    };
    //ensure when the model is first instantiated, it will attempt to load 
    //whatever data was passed in if it's not null or undefined
    self.load(data);     
}
```

Edit:

Now you have the flexibility of cleanly passing in the data to the model's constructor in addition to deferring data loading later by explicitly invoking `load()` if the need arises.

Comment: How do I get the data into the model though, without tedious `getElementById`'s? The data *is already present* in the DOM, bringing it into JavaScript directly seems gratuitous.

Comment: When you design a knockout page, the data is never loaded into the html itself. That is the whole point of the model, to separate the data from it's presentation. You need to refactor the data out of your html and load it into your model by other means such as serializing your data as json. What server-side language are you using?

Comment: C#. These elements are ASP controls which are pre-populated after IsValid fails. They already have value assigned and storing the data elsewhere (such as in JSON in another script tag on the page) would involve quite a bit more engineering for something which should be relatively cheap.

Comment: @cwallenpoole Unfortunately, there is nothing to be done but having to redesign your pages to leverage knockout completely by adopting the methodology of serializing the data and populating your model with it. Otherwise, it really won't matter because the ViewState on your ASP controls will never stay in sync with the knockout models and you'll have a nightmare on your hands. It's an all or nothing proposition.

Comment: I just used the system suggested in http://stackoverflow.com/q/11596933/866172.

Comment: How do you plan to deal with the ASP controls' ViewState not staying in sync with what your KO model is storing?

Comment: Once the initial state is loaded the ASP controls' original state is meaningless. 

Without creating some arbitrary script tag which holds the data, how you you suggest someone populate the observables? And even if you do do that, you're *still* storing data in the DOM, only now you're arguably storing it *twice*. Moving initialization data into some file which sends out script tag headers doesn't really help either: you run severe sync. issues that way.

Comment: More importantly, the data *is already there*. It is *in the value attribute already*. Putting extra data anywhere else will *add complexity* and make it harder to maintain. And keeping it "in sync" is more-or-less irrelevant anyway: there are plenty of cases where a change of state in JS will not carry over to an actual change in node attributes.

Comment: Further, even if synchronization were an issue, the fact of the matter is that KO keeps the original nodes' values synced to what the the observable's value. The problem I had was that KO does this destructively &mdash; it erases the value before it starts synchronizing. It would be better if 0 arguments translated to "keep the original value", but that is not an option.