# How to set the default value of ko.observable to the default value of the control itself in ASP.NET and KnockoutJS?

Tags: c#, asp.net, knockout.js

I have an ASP.NET C# web page with KnockoutJS bound controls:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtOfferName" placeholder="Offer Name" data-bind="value: planName"></asp:TextBox>
```

and

```
planName: ko.observable("")
```

...set on document load. It all works great when txtOfferName should start off as blank. Now, I want to set the value of txtOfferName to something that's not blank during Page_Load. If I just do

```
txtOfferName.Text = "New Value";
```

it won't work because ko.observable("") will overwrite the value once it gets bound. Is there a way to bind an observable and have it default to the initial value of the control it's bound to? I can certainly do

```
ko.observable("New Value")
```

but the values are coming from the database, so it'd be much more difficult to set them in the front-end, rather than backend. Worst case scenario, I can serialize all those values, put them into a hidden field and assign them using KO, but I wanted to check in case there's an easier way first.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you considered having an AJAX call to get the data and then calling `ko.applyBindings` on the JSON returned which can be mapped to your view model?

Comment: I can JSON the data server-side and put it into a hidden field to avoid doing AJAX completely. I was just wondering if there's something like ko.observableDefaultValue() so the original value will be grabbed from the element and then bound to the model going forward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<%@ Page ClientIDMode="Static" %>
<input type="hidden" runat="server" id="hdnOfferName" />
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtOfferName" placeholder="Offer Name" data-bind="value: planName"></asp:TextBox>

                //code behind
                hdnOfferName.Value = "New Value";

        //javascript (this is $jquery, use document.getElementById() for javascript)
     planName = ko.observable($("#hdnOfferName").val());
```

Comment: Yep, that was my first guess, but the view model is in a separate .js file, so <% %> stuff won't work there.

Comment: I have edited my answer so that you can achieve the solution without <% %>. I have added ClientIDMode="Static" to the @Page declaration, this tells asp.net to render ids as is. Now, in your js you can trust the id of the hidden input. If you have repeaters/datagrids in your aspx you may, but not likely, have unexpected behavior, it just depends on what you are doing with your repeaters/datagrids.

Answer (score 0):

[How to extend knockout observables to read default value from binding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11596933/how-to-extend-knockout-observables-to-read-default-value-from-binding)

This answer to basically the same question is your best, most flexible option. When the binding initializes, it will store whatever the current value of the input is in the observable

Comment: Nik I. it is important to note that this referenced answer for a ASP.NET MVC web app. The answer uses the razor engine syntax so the <% %> you are familiar with is replaced with the simplified @. Note @Model.SomeValue in the referenced answer.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used KO with WebForms, but I think it's the same idea with MVC. In ASP.NET MVC, I set defaults before calling `ko.applyBinding` like this...

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" data-bind="value: planName"></asp:TextBox>

<script src="viewModel.js" />

<script type="text/javascript">
  myViewModel.planName('<%=Stuff.planName%>');
  ko.applyBinding(myViewModel);
</script>
```